# What do the souvenirs from my Pokémon GO buddy do?

Tags: pokemon-go

Recently, Pokémon GO has added a new mechanic where your buddy can find a souvenir for you. However, the souvenirs seem to be completely random, and unrelated to gameplay benefits, e.g., I have a stretchy spring and a torn ticket.

[image: souvenirs from buddy]

Is there any use or benefit to these souvenirs?

Answer (score 15):

No, there is not a use or benefit to these souvenirs currently. There are some speculations as to what they might do in the future, but nothing has been confirmed by Niantic yet.

Answer (score 11):

Only one that has a benefit is the “Lone Earring” souvenir that gives the player earrings that match the souvenir

[image: Earring souvenir]

Comment: Can you add a picture of your avatar wearing this item?